# Создание элемента массива с конкретным именем

Tags: java

есть метод, который возвращает int, нужно заполнить только что созданный массив этими int-ами, да так, чтобы у каждого элемента было свое имя и при возможности можно было обратиться к нему не по индексу, а по имени, это возможно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, возможно. Нужен двухмерный массив со строками с String значениями и столбцами  int, но для этого нужно знать размер массива изначально. Либо использовать java коллекции, а именно map. И лучше формировать этот массив уже в методе, либо использовать отдельный объект итератор на котором вызывать next, чтоб  возвращать след. int и добавлять его в массив/коллекцию, если конечно вы не имели ввиду просто вызвать этот метод определённое количество раз для массива

Answer (score 0):

Для этой цели существует специальная структура данных, называется она dictionary или map.
В ЯП Java есть реализации `HashMap`, `Hashtable` и `LinkedHashMap`.
Вот пример использования

```
// создаём словарь, где ключ имеет тип String, а значение Integer
Hashtable<String, Integer> my_dict = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();

// Таким образом добавляем два значения
my_dict.put("a", 101); // ключ - строка "a", а значение 101
my_dict.put("b", 202); // ключ - строка "b", а значение 202

// выведем значение, которое лежит с ключом (индесом) "a"
System.out.println("\nValue at key = a : " + my_dict.get("a"));

// Вот так можно удалить значение с ключом (индексом) "a"
my_dict.remove("a");
```

Остальные операции и возможности почитайте в более подробных статьях и источниках